# How to get substring based on special characters in android?

Tags: java, android, substring

Actually this is a very simple question, I tried a lot but I am unable to get the exact solution. I have a string like:

```
String mystring = "one<1234567>,two<98765432>,three<878897656>";
```

Here I want the data which is inside `"<"` and `">"`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It would help if you post what you have tried "a lot".

Comment: you want the string inside the < ? >, e.g 1234567 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use regex

```
String str = "one<1234567>,two<98765432>,three<878897656>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>").matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
    String v = m.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String mystring = "one<1234567>,two<98765432>,three<878897656>";
    String[] result = mystring.split(",");
    for (String s : result) {
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf("<")+1);
        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(">"));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**Print result :**

```
1234567
98765432
878897656
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like `<(.*?)>` :

```
String mystring = "one<1234567>,two<98765432>,three<878897656>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mystring);
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String mystring = "one<1234567>,two<98765432>,three<878897656>";
String[] a = myString.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
String substr=a[i].subString(a[i].indexOf("<"),a[i].indexOf(">"));
System.out.println(substr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if your inner bracket value always numeric and outside alphabetical i.e. <, >

```
String[] strings=mystring.replaceAll("[a-z<>]", "").split(",");

         for(String string:stringsArray)
         { 
          System.out.println(string);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found an new solution from `StringTokenizer` class

you can use it as,

```
 StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(KEY_SUBFOLDERNAME, ".");
            String first_string = tokens.nextToken();
            File_Ext = tokens.nextToken();
            System.out.println("First_string : "+first_string);
            System.out.println("File_Ext : "+File_Ext);
```